# Multiple variables for a 'in (select...)' statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I want to do something like this:

```
select value1, value2, value3, value4, count(1)
from mytable
where value1, value2, value3, value4 in
    (select value1, value2, value3, value4 from mytable
     where record_no = 1 and value5 = 'foobar')
group by value1, value2, value3, value4
having count(1)>4;
```

That is, I want to find values1-4 for all the groups of 1-4 that have a specific property on atleast one of their records, and I want just the  groups that have have more than four records.

**Update for clarification**

```
select * from mytable;
```

will give you something like

```
value1    value2    value3   value4   record_no    value5    lots more columns
------    ------    ------   ------   ---------    ------    -----------------
aaa       bbb       ccc      ddd      1            foobar
aaa       bbb       ccc      ddd      2            abcdef
aaa       bbb       ccc      ddd      3            zzzzzz
aaa       bbb       ccc      ddd      4            barfoo
aaa       bbb       ccc      ddd      5            dsnmatr
a1        b1        c1       d1       1            foobar
a1        b1        c1       d1       2            foobar
a2        b2        c2       d2       1            barfoo
a2        b2        c2       d2       2            barfoo
```

I want to find the values of value1, value2, value3, value4
For all the groups of value1, value2, value3, value4, that have record 1 having 'foobar' as its value5, and where the group size is >4.

eg it should return

```
value1    value2    value3   value4 
------    ------    ------   ------  
aaa       bbb       ccc      ddd
```

Comment: Your example makes absolutely no sense, and your explanation isn't really clear. Can you [edit] your question and post some sample data and the output you'd like to get from that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close to begin with. This part was the problem:

```
where value1, value2, value3, value4 in
```

You have to treat `value1, value2, value3, value4` as a set, so just put parentheses around them like so:

```
where (value1, value2, value3, value4) in
```

Here's the whole query; the only thing changed from your post is the parentheses:

```
select value1, value2, value3, value4, count(1)
from mytable
where (value1, value2, value3, value4) in
    (select value1, value2, value3, value4
    from mytable
    where record_no = 1 and value5 = 'foobar')
group by value1, value2, value3, value4
having count(1) > 4;
```

There's a SQL Fiddle of this [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d81b/2).

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple variables I often concatenate the items together with some character that does not occur, so

```
where value1 + '|' + value2 + '|' + value3 in (
    select value1 + '|' + value2 + '|' + value3 from ...
```

if I have three fields. Equality will only be true if all the values are the same, achieving the result.

Comment: Is the problem with this solution, that it becomes a very expensive string comparison operation?

Comment: It can be slow, but like Microsoft SQL Server don't offer multi-value `in` clause comparison, so you do what you need to do. I had missed the Oracle tag. It is a reason why in T-SQL I tend to add a synthetic key on complex join tables that might need such a query: I can join across the synthetic key and index the candidate keys, avoiding such constructs.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
select  value1, value2, value3, value4, count(*)
from    mytable
group by value1, value2, value3, value4
having  count(*) > 4 
and     sum(decode(record_no , 1 , 1 , 0)) = 1
and     sum(decode(value5 , 'foobar' , 1 , 0) = 1;
```

it's a little trick with decode. it's should work fine.

for educational purposes, if you don't need and actual data from the sub query (this is your case) it's a good idea to always use `EXISTS`. 
in your example it would be

```
select value1, value2, value3, value4, count(*)
from mytable
where exists 
    (select 1 
     from   mytable b
     where  b.record_no = 1 
     and    b.value5 = 'foobar'
     and    b.value1 = a.value1
     and    b.value2 = a.value2 
     and    b.value3 = a.value3
     and    b.value4 = a.value4
     )
group by value1, value2, value3, value4
having count(1) > 4;
```